# Nginx upstream unix socket keepalive?

Tags: php, nginx

Do I need to add any additional configuration to enable keepalive to my PHP-FPM backend?

```
    upstream php_backend {
            zone upstreams 64K;
            server unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock max_fails=1 fail_timeout=2s;
            keepalive 10;
    }

        # Pass off php requests to PHP-FPM
    location ~* \.php {
            try_files       $uri =404;
            access_log      /var/log/php-fpm/example_access.log;
            include         /usr/local/etc/nginx/php-fpm.conf;
            fastcgi_pass    php_backend;
    }
```

In the following Nginx guides, when you don't use unix sockets you must add :

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header   "Connection" "";
```

Source :

https://www.nginx.com/blog/avoiding-top-10-nginx-configuration-mistakes/#no-keepalives
https://www.nginx.com/blog/avoiding-top-10-nginx-configuration-mistakes/#upstream-groups

Is there any additional config I need to add when using a unix socket?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change `keepalive_timeout` value in `nginx.conf`.

In linux (Debian) it is located in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`:

[image: nginx.conf]

And restart your server with: `sudo service nginx restart`.

You may also restart fpm after any change in config with `sudo service  php7.4-fpm restart`. (It is `php7.4-fpm` in may case)

To see all available services use `systemctl list-units --type=service --all`